# dynamic row creation php and html

Tags: php, mysql

i want to make a table from a mysql query
where the table should show like

```
pic1       pic2     pic3
name1      name2    name3
-------------------------
pic4       pic5     pic6
name4      name5    name6
```

please say how it is possible by using php and html?

---

ok,it will show picture and corresponding name,picture1 will be a picture same as pic2,pic3 etc,name1 is a name of corresponding as like orkut or face book,i have tried like 
code;-

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <? for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
            ?>

            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"><a href="#"><img src="images/speak-pic.jpg" width="88" height="88"
                                                                       border="0" class="pic-bod"/></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top"><a href="#" class="link-ar"><? echo $t["profile_name"]?>  </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>



        <?
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
<?
}
```

Comment: What's the data you're starting with; have you tried anything so far; if so, where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: Now, when you say it should look like that, do you mean a real table, or do you mean plain text to come out just like that? Where does your question really lie, the PHP or the HTML? We generally like to solve specific problems, rather than do an entire task for someone.

Answer (score 0):

First get the result from the query and loop it.

```
// first make the connection..., then
$sql = "SELECT xxxxxx";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
foreach($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc()) {
  // put the echo statement here with the apropriate html tags.
}
```

if you want to learn deep, catch this link from sitepoing.com
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/php-gallery-system-minutes