# how to create dynamic row in php and html

Tags: php, html

I need to create a table in runtime by using php and html,the table should look like:-

```
image1      image2        image3
name1       name2         name3
---------------------------------
image4      image5       image6
name4       name5        name6
```

total 2 rows,each row containing 3 data,each data again containing 2 rows,one is a image and another is one name filed.

I have already tried like:

```
for($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
{
  ?> <tr>
   <? for($j=0;$j<3;$j++)
   {
   ?>
        <td>
                <table>
                    <tr> 
                         <td align="left" valign="top" >
                             <a href="#"> 
                              <img src="images/speak-pic.jpg" width="88" height="88" border="0" class="pic-bod" />
                              </a>
                          </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                           <td align="left" valign="top" >
                             <a href="#" class="link-ar">
                               <? echo $t["profile_name"]?>  
                             </a>
                           </td>
                    </tr>
                 </table> 
             </td>

      <?
   } 
   ?>
   </tr>
<? }
?>
```

but it is still not working

Comment: Your code has been garbled with the question's content. Try fixing it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the "01010100" toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic row creation php and html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226110/dynamic-row-creation-php-and-html)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the use of the short-form tag.  Use `<?php` to start an inline PHP block.

On another note, it looks like your code there is missing a good chunk.  Or you posted a strange excerpt.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are not really giving us enough code to help you, here some pointers to help you.

Firstly you are not describing very much what the problem is. The html looks solid, and the php looks boilerplate code.

- However you might think it looks as a table, this is not really tabular data. Just a bunch of images with an attached link, grouped three per row. If you look it that way, it might be easier to format it with block elements (like div) and CSS. This allows for a floating design which doesn't need special cases when you have 7 elements and you need a row for only one item.
- PHP has a lot of operators to make this kind of code more readable. If you look at http://fi.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php you can for example find the following syntax:

  ```
  <?php foreach($dataarray as $datarow): ?>
      do_something($data);
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  ```

When you update your question with more information, I could expand this post with more help.

Answer (score -1):

First of all we are going to create simple contact form in HTML which allows

viewers to enter their information like “Full Name”, ”Subject”, ”E-mail”,

“Message” these are common values that we want in our contact form.

And then we will create PHP form to process these and send the mail. So first

create new HTML file and name it as “index.html”.

```
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>

<head>

<title>Simple Contact Us Form</title>

<meta http-equiv=”Content- Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″ />

<link rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css” href=”style.css” />

</head>

<body>

<div id=”page-wrap”>

<h1 align =”center”>Simple <strong>Contact Us</strong> Form</h1>

<div id=”form-area”>

<form method=”post” action=”contactengine.php”>

<label for=”Name”>Name:</label>

<input type=”text” name=”Name” id=”Name” required/>

<label for=”number”>Contact Number:</label>

<input type=”text” name=”number” id=”number”

required/>

<label for=”Email”>Email:</label>

<input type=”text” name=”Email” id=”Email” required/>

<label for=”Enquiry”>Message:</label><br />

<textarea name=”message” rows=”20″ cols=”20″

id=”message”></textarea>

<input type=”submit” name=”submit” value=”Submit”

class=”submit-button” />

</form>

</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

you may got this answers on http://lotsofthing.com/send-mail-using-php-html/